# How to declare a typed array in typescript in vue props

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am trying to create a vue component using vue 3 and composition api with typescript so I have the following:

```html
<template>
    ...removed for minimal sake
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
    import { StyledSelectItem } from './StyledSelectItem';

    export default defineComponent({
        name: 'StyledSelect',
        props: {
            cssClass: String,
            items: Array<StyledSelectItem>,
            placeholder: String,
            selectedValue: String,
        },
        setup() {

        },
    });
</script>
```

With the styled select item being an interface:

```ts
export interface StyledSelectItem {
    text: String,
    value: String,
}
```

But it is failing to compile saying there is an unexpected token:

```
  14 |     props: {
  15 |         cssClass: String,
> 16 |         items: Array < StyledSelectItem > ,
     |                                           ^
  17 |         placeholder: String,
  18 |         selectedValue: String,
  19 |     },
```

I have also tried using the following with no joy:

```
items: StyledSelectItem[],        // fails with refers to a type but used as a value
items: [] as StyledSelectItem[],  // fails with no overload matches this call.
```

How do I declare the typed array?

Comment: Unlikely this is related to the issue, but generally you'd want to use `string` rather than `String` for a type definition ( https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html )

Comment: yeah I removed the broken code and just got that error :0

Comment: I am not sure but have you tried Array as PropType<StyledSelectItem[]>?

Comment: @fOURP `PropType` seems to be a react thing - I get an error cannot find name 'PropType'

Comment: Sorry, you have to import it first. import type { PropType } from 'vue' ; i am not sure if this is the solution but you can give it a try

Comment: @fOURP that seems to have worked, thanks :)